# How to access local server on a PC using Opera Mobile

Tags: localhost, opera, mobile-browser, opera-mobile

I am trying to test my website on Opera Mobile on my PC. But I am not able to connect to the local server using the mobile browser. Could any one of you tell me what all settings need to be changed in order to make this thing work?

Your answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Yamini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Opera Mobile in non turbo or non mini mode should work for accessing your locally hosted server.

Try going into the **Settings of Opera Mobile and turning off Compression/Mini/Turbo**.

Then you should be able to access your localhost/127.0.0.1 hosted site.

Alternatively, try using the IP address of your own machine rather than the local address.

Comment: Hi @David Freitas, Thanks you for your quick response. I have turned the settings off, but still I am not able to connect. :-(

Comment: Have you tried using the machine's IP instead of a local address? Can you access the site from a normal browser on the same PC as the Opera Mobile emulator is running?

Comment: Freistas, Thanks for your replies. It is working now. I tried to add loop back alias, but that disconnected me from the internet. I tried that many times, I am not sure if that loopback alias worked or not, but I can connect to the local server now. I used IP address instead of local address, and it started working. Thanks for the information, it was real, ly helpful

Comment: @YaminiIndrakanti, it's a pleasure, don't forget to mark the answer as correct or upvote if you think it's a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the Opera Mobile Emulator from http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/ ? If so, you should be able to access any web/IP address, just like in a normal web browser.

In case you're trying to run a copy of Opera Mini in the MicroEmulator, then it's likely you can't access a local server - your site will need to be published (e.g. on a secret URL) so the Opera Mini servers can reach it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It is working now. I tried to add loop back alias, but that disconnected me from the internet. I tried that many times, I am not sure if that loopback alias worked or not, but I can connect to the local server now. I used IP address  instead of local address, and it started working. Thanks for the information, it was real, ly helpful.

Comment: To get around the issue of Opera Mini not working on localhost you can use: NPM localtunnel. Worked perfectly for my needs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel