# Access a test website in local LAN

Tags: mobile, web, lan

I have one computer with test websites set up.
I can access the test-sites from other computers.

Now I want to do some changes to make the sites mobile friendly.

I can not access the websites with my android mobile.

Problem 1: Can't edit /etc/hosts on my android

Problem 2: If I enter 192.168.2.77 in the URL Bar of a browser in any computer I get the master test site corrctly.
Doing the same with the android device I just get a timed-out error.

any help apreciated

Comment: Is your website running on a port?

Comment: No - well rather on port 80 as usual. If I enter 192.168.2.77:80 from the browser on the computer I get what I expect.

Comment: Did you set Internet permission for your phone yet?

Comment: Pardon, what do you mean with "internet pemission"?

Comment: If you go to Google chrome (from your device) and type `192.168.2.77` you can see your website in local LAN?

Comment: Is your mobile connected to your LAN when you are trying to access the IP '192.168.2.77'?

Also have you enabled incoming firewall rule "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)" if you have test websites set up on a Windows machine?

Comment: Funny, it works with chrome (never used it on the device - always using opera). Its an apache server on debian

Comment: Will this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679100/how-to-access-local-server-on-a-pc-using-opera-mobile) help resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've `INTERNET permission` in your `manifest.xml` file

```
<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> //this line of code
<application>
....
</manifest>
```

Comment: It may sound stupid but where is the manifest.xml located?
Web server is an apache2

Comment: On your `Android` project

Comment: Do you have an Android APP? or you just want to open your `192.168.2.77` in your device?

Comment: I just want to open the site using the browser on my android

Comment: I knew it.... this is not about Android codding..... well... I did something like this are you tried to open the advanced options on your Wifi/condiguration/ your SSID and put the same Acces point?

Comment: see above. It works with chrome from my android device but not with opera (default browser)...

Comment: Ya, you should configure Opera like this : `Settings of Opera Mobile and turning off Compression/Mini/Turbo` as [David d C e Freitas said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7679303/4385913)

Comment: I don't have that in options - probably due to using opera mini

Comment: Is that a problem if you use Google Chrome? or try with other navigator?

Comment: No problm using chrome. Just find it strange that opera doesn't handle it in the way I would ecpect it to.

Comment: If you solved the problem feel free to upvote or mark this answer as a correct if I helped to you